# I can not find keycloak web resources deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, keycloak

I deployed keycloak in tomcat with eclipse Luna based on this tutorial: https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2015/01/14/deploying-keycloak-in-tomcat/#comment-245

I have it running in my machine and have no problem. Now I have to edit the login form based on my company design. But I do not have local files .css and .htmls to do it.

This is the parent project and some war configuration.

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>keycloak-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>keycloak-war</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Keycloak Server</name>
<description />
```

Do I have to donwload the war project, the parent project? I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please be informed that it is recommended to use standalone Keycloak server - http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/server-installation.html)

And here some details how you are able to customize themes - http://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.0-alpha-3/userguide/html/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip the keycloak-forms-common-themes-1.1.0.Beta2.jar  and under login you can change the css and images and redeploy it